# Issue while reading the header row cell values in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, closedxml

The excel that I am uploading in my application, the `header row` is at row number **3**. I want to read the row number **3** and add it to the `list<string>` variable. While reading row 3 with the specific cell range, its counting the cell but not reading the values. The header row is enabled with the `filter`. I am using `ClosedXML.Excel` library for this.

**Code:**

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    // Get the header row
    var headerRow = new List<string>();
    var usedRange = ws.Range("A3:AD3");                        
    foreach(var cell in usedRange.Cells())
    {
        headerRow.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
    }                       

}
```

Comment: You can try `headerRow.Add(cell.GetValue<string>());`.